# useState() do double render

Tags: reactjs, render, react-hooks

I'm using useState() in function component and first render is calling twice. Is it correct or mistake? If it is correct why does it render twice? setCount renders the component twice too.

```
function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  console.log("render");

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('uu5'));
```

Thanks

Comment: I see the render being called only once. IT may depend on some other portion of your app. https://codesandbox.io/s/zkmqv84krx

Comment: @Ondrej how many times is parent component rendered?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to react docs, it's an intentional feature to help you to detect unexpected side effects if you're using StrictMode

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> - Class component constructor, render, and shouldComponentUpdate
>     methods
> - Class component static getDerivedStateFromProps method
> - Function component bodies
> - State updater functions (the first argument
>     to setState)
> - **Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer**
>
> Note:
>   This only applies to development mode. Lifecycles will not be double-invoked in production mode.

https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in React DevTools. When console is closed, component is rendered just one times. But if you open React DevTools and reload the page, render will be shown two times. Open [example](https://zkmqv84krx.codesandbox.io/) and try it. (React 16.8.3)

Comment: You saved me a ton of head scratching. Thank you!

Comment: Is this still a problem? I have the same issue.

Comment: been here, asked myself the same.

Answer (score 1):

remove <React.StrictMode> wrapper in the index.js file