# React rerender process seem to act unnormal

Tags: reactjs

```
function App() {
  return <Store></Store>;
}
```

```
export function Store() {
    console.log("render Store");
    useState(()=>{
        console.log("useState")
    })
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("mount");
        return ()=>{ console.log("unmount");};
    },[])
    return <div>??</div>
}
```

The console will log`render Store`=>`useState`=>`render Store`=>`useState`=>`mount`.
Lazy load of `useState` run 2 time,`Store` rerender without any reason.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YW6gX.png)

It's very confused.

Comment: I find the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54927622/usestate-do-double-render ,the devto

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your component in `StrictMode`

```js
<React.StrictMode>
    <Store/>
</React.StrictMode>
```

Answer (score 0):

React hooks run on each render cycle. State was initialized to `undefined and triggered second render (render phase), then component was mounted (commit phase).

[image]

Granted this diagram uses the class-based component's lifecycle functions, but the process is the same for functional components.