# Material ui useStyles() logs two times

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Whenever I add 'useStyles()' it forces to log any line two times.

Example:

```
function App() {
    console.log('1')
    const classes = useStyles()  // adding this logs in console '1' twice

    return (
        <Fragment/>
    )
```

Why it happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using the snippet below it actually renders once.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(count);
  });
```

[full answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61053432/react-usestate-cause-double-rendering/61053571#61053571)