# Component rerendering in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am working on react app where one of my component when I place `console.log('Hello')` it keeps on re-rendering. I am not sure why. This is How my component looks.
Any help would be great

> DispensingIncident.jsx

```
const DispensingIncidents = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const {
    getFilterData,
    dispensingData,
    getPeriodList,
    getTypeList,
    getOverviewData,
    location,
    history,
  } = props;

  const [timeSpan, setTimeSpan] = React.useState("Monthly");
  const [year, setYear] = React.useState(2020);
  const [tabValue, setTabValue] = React.useState(0);
  const [spanData, setSpanData] = React.useState([]);
  const [dataType, setDataType] = React.useState("aim");
  const {
    loading,
    duration,
    period,
    type,
    dispensingOverviewData,
    overviewDataLoading,
  } = dispensingData;
  const { count } = dispensingOverviewData;
  // console.log("props", duration["monthly"][0].period);
  console.log("Hellowo");
  useEffect(() => {
    getPeriodList();
    getTypeList();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    history.replace({
      pathname: location.pathname,
      search: `?year=${year}&period=${timeSpan}`,
    });
    setYear(year);
    setTimeSpan(timeSpan);
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [year, timeSpan]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getFilterData(year);
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [year]);

  /**
   * GET query from url search param
   *  @usage query.get("year")
   */
  function useQuery() {
    return new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  }
  const query = useQuery();

  /**
   *
   * @param {*} event
   * @param {*} newValue
   * on tab change
   */

  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const handleTabChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setTabValue(newValue);
  };

  /**
   * Year change
   * @param {*} event
   */
  const handleYearChange = (event) => {
    setYear(event.target.value);
    setTimeSpan(query.get("period"));
  };

  /**
   * Span change
   * @param {*} event
   */
  const handleSpanChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;

    setTimeSpan(value);
  };

  const time = query.get("period");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (time === "Yearly") {
      const yearlyData = duration["yearly"];
      setSpanData(yearlyData);
    } else if (time === "Weekly") {
      const weeklyData = duration["weekly"];
      setSpanData(weeklyData);
    } else if (time === "Quarterly") {
      const quarterlyData = duration["quarterly"];
      setSpanData(quarterlyData);
    } else if (time === "Monthly") {
      const monthlyData = duration["monthly"];
      setSpanData(monthlyData);
    } else if (time === "6 months") {
      const halfYearlyData = duration["half-yearly"];
      setSpanData(halfYearlyData);
    }
  }, [time, duration]);

  const handleSpanTabChange = (data) => {
    getOverviewData(year, data.period.to, data.period.from, dataType);
  };
  const handleDataTypeChange = (event) => {
    setDataType(event.target.value);
  };

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <Loading/>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div className={classes.dispenseRoot}>
      <Paper
        elementType="div"
        elevation={5}
        square={true}
        variant="elevation"
        className={classes.topContainer}
      >
           // content here......
        </Paper>
    </div>
  );
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    dispensingData: state.dispensing,
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  getFilterData: (year) =>
    dispatch({ type: GET_DISPENSING_INCIDENT_FILTER_DATA, year }),
  getPeriodList: () => dispatch({ type: GET_DISPENSING_INCIDENT_PERIOD_LIST }),
  getTypeList: () => dispatch({ type: GET_DISPENSING_INCIDENT_TYPE_LIST }),
  getOverviewData: (period, to, from, datatype) =>
    dispatch({ type: GET_DISPENSING_OVERVIEW, period, from, to, datatype }),
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(DispensingIncidents);
```

> This is what happeing when i put `console.log('Hello')`

[image: hellopw]

Comment: Don't place console logs and other functions with side-effects directly in the function body of a functional component. Can you clarify more what you mean by "keeps rerendering"?

Comment: @DrewReese i have added image to my question. This is what happening in my component. Is it normal ?

Comment: You've several effect hooks and you've not provided the steps to reproduce so we've no idea what you may be doing to cause the issue. If you log in an effect do you see as many? `useEffect(() => console.log('render'));` This will log only ***once*** per render, so you can see how many times it is really rerendering.

Comment: I tried to put `console.log('render')` in every useEffect  no where it is shown more then twice or thrice.

Comment: Then I think this is possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61053432/react-usestate-cause-double-rendering/61053571#61053571 if you are rendering your app into a `React.StrictMode` element. If you are getting only one log per effect then this is normal behavior.