# Why useEffect is working twice even if I change the data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-effect

I try to call a method in service class from MainPanel with useEffect hook:

Here is my MainPannel:

```
function MainPanel() {

  const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([]);
  

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCustomers = async () => {
      const customers = await getCustomerList();
      setCustomers({ customers });
      console.log(customers)
    };
    getCustomers()
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* do something */}

    </div>
  );
}

export default MainPanel;
```

And here is the service method that I called from useEffect:

```
export async function getCustomerList() {

    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/customer", { params: { id: 1 } })
    .then(response => console.log(response.data))
}
```

In this scenario useEffect is working but working twice and console.log is printing twice (2 times log correct value and 2 times undefined).

If I just get the data with return statement instead of printing to console like

```
export async function getCustomerList() {

    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/customer", { params: { id: 1 } })
    .then(response => {return response.data})
}
```

Same thing happening but this time response is coming as **undefined**. I know they are separate problems but I just need to understand a proper way of fetching data and use it in useEffect only once.

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: are you using `<React.StrictMode>` in your app.js or index.js?

Comment: what does `getCustomers()` do?

Comment: @miyavmiyav it is in index.js and between it there is <App />

Comment: the strict mode renders components two times if its in production build or you remove it it will trigger useEffect only once

Comment: @miyavmiyav for now it is doing nothing but what I want to do is just call function and get data at beginning and initialize to a variable and then use it as a datasource

Comment: @miyavmiyav `React.StrictMode` only works in non-production builds. See the note at the ***top*** of the [page](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html). "Note: Strict mode checks are run in development mode only; they do not impact the production build."

Comment: @DrewReese thats why I said in production OR if you disable it it will fire only once

Comment: @miyavmiyav Oh, I see, grammar fail. I read that comment as "the strict mode renders components two times if its in production build *or* you remove it it will trigger useEffect only once". Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `return` in your function `getCustomerList`.

```
export async function getCustomerList() {
    return axios.get("http://localhost:8080/customer", { params: { id: 1 } });    
}
```

And get data like the following:

```
      const res = await getCustomerList();
      setCustomers({ res.data.customers });
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably `React.StrictMode` is firing the useEffect twice as for returning the values you should probably just do as the other answer ( @Liki Crus) suggests

Comment: I don't think this is the case since the `useEffect` hook has an empty dependency array. Seems something is mounting the component twice.

Comment: @DrewReese if dependency array is empty it fires once on render of component and it gets rendered twice because of `React.StrictMode`

Comment: See [detecting unexpected side-effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects), it's not one of the double invoked functions. Or check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61053571/8690857) for more in-depth explanation between "render" and "render to the DOM".

Comment: but render is triggered twice and its triggering useEffect on render.

Comment: you can read about that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618844/react-hooks-useeffect-is-called-twice-even-if-an-empty-array-is-used-as-an-ar#:~:text=company%20blog-,React%20Hooks%3A%20useEffect()%20is%20called%20twice%20even%20if%20an,is%20used%20as%20an%20argument&text=Bookmark%20this%20question.

Comment: Thanks. That other answer appears to be in agreement with the answer I linked you. "render" triggered twice, yes, during the "render phase", the `useEffect` hook is once per *render to the DOM*, i.e. the "commit phase", no matter what. Cheers.